# Magento 2.3.2 google shopping ads channel have keep uploading product feeds after uninstall by composer

Tags: magento2.3.2, google-api, google-product-feeds

Do you know how to uninstall this module completely with database?
or How I can stop using google content api?

and I noticed that google merchant center account created within installing process of this extension become  **a sub account** and it is not able to close this account without permission of main account.

Comment: I already have removed Content API feed several times.
but after I deleted, the feed re-upload automatically in irregular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove the feed in Merchant Center, as Google does not do this automatically. [The steps to do this is their docs.](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/7438535?hl=en)